# trouble using posted form data in express/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

Currently this is what I have:

Here's my Post method

```
app.post('/barchartentry', function(req, res){
        res.render('barchart', { title: 'EZgraph: Bar Chart', barValues: req.body.myInputs, labelValues: req.body.myLabel});
    });
```

Here's my view in Jade:

```
extends layout

block appendHeader
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/barchart.css')

block content
    include navbar
    canvas(id='canvas' width="800" height="600")
    include copyright


block appendScripts
    script(src='js/barchart.js')
```

And here's the JS file in that view, I need to access the data I sent in this file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var values = barValues;
        var labels = labelValues;

        console.dir(barValues);

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

        canvas.fillStyle="#BFBFBF";
        canvas.fillRect(0,0,800,600);

        canvas.fillStyle="#000000";
        canvas.beginPath();

        canvas.moveTo(40, 40);
        canvas.lineTo(40, 560);
        canvas.lineTo(760, 560);
        canvas.stroke();
});
```

Using the input data, I'll draw a bar chart with the given numbers/labels. Currently I can't access this data though even after giving it to the page. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do something else with it to make it available to that script to use?

Comment: Load the page with no parameters, then fire and AJAX request back to get those values, once AJAX completes, assign them to your chart.

Comment: Where are `barValues` and `labelValues` defined?

Comment: They're input data from a form on another page, that data gets posted by the first post method. The data exists and gets that far at least, as I've used console.dir to see it.

Comment: I've never used AJAX, this is all new to me and I'm trying to learn. Where would I find out how to do what you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vaguely remember having problems attempting to substitute values into a jade script. Additionally it feels a little smelly to dynamically generate javascript. So I bind data to DOM and access it programmatically:

```
block content
  include navbar
  canvas(
  id='canvas',
  width="800",
  height="600",
  data-barValues=JSON.stringify(locals.barValues),
  data-labelValues=JSON.stringify(locals.labelValues)
  )
  include copyright
```

and then in js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = $('#canvas').attr('data-barValues').val();
  values = JSON.parse(values);
  var labels = $('#canvas').attr('data-labelValues').val();
  labels = JSON.parse(labels);
  ...
});
```

Comment: Nice, that's a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Although  you're passing the value of `barValues` and `labelValues` into your Jade view, you're not rendering their values into the HTML, so your JS script can't reference it

In jade, do something like

```
script. 
    var values = barValues;
    var labels = labelValues;
```

Comment: I had suspicion it was something like this but I couldn't find anything about it online!

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.